# Using nw.js to build a native code binary from your javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-platform, node-webkit, .app

I have built an app for osx which runs nwjs.  Right now the app is simple - I am just running the nwjs binary and pointing it to the root of a web application.

I'd like to make use of nwjs's java script protection feature - in which you can build your javascript in to native code and load that binary with nwjs.  This can be read about here: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/

My question is twofold:

1. Suppose I have an entire js/ folder which stores each of my javascript files, and that that js/ folder has multiple other subfolders.  Do I need to run nwjc for every single javascript file?  I noticed the option of --nw-module, but can this apply to a directory with multiple subfolders in it?  Also, once you have built the binary, what do you do about the  tags in the html that were loading the regular js files before?  Can those stay the same, or do they need to change?)
2. I am restricted to building my app on Linux.  The nwjs documentation says: "**The compiled code is not cross-platform nor compatible between versions of NW.js. So you’ll need to run nwjc for each of the platforms when you package your application**."    Does anyone know of any tools which overcome this issue?  I have found multiple tools such as Web2Executable, etc., which provide cross platform support.  But I need to make use of nwjs's java script protection.  Do any of these tools give a way to utilize this?